# Arduino Due Digital Inputs without Response

Tags: pins, arduino-due, input

On two of my Arduino Due, when connecting the pin `3.3V` to any digital inputs (`37`,`36`,`35`,`34`), no serial message nor `LED_BUILTIN` is thrown as output, only the `Test` message.

Digital Pins are set as `INPUT` by default. [`Blink`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/tutorial/blink) works.

I have never connected any other thing on those pins, even 5V.

What I am missing?

```
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    while(!Serial);
    pinMode(LED_BUILTIN,OUTPUT);
    Serial.print("Test");
}

void loop() {
    if (digitalRead(37))
        Serial.print("37");
    if (digitalRead(36))
        Serial.print("36");
    if (digitalRead(35))
        Serial.print("35");
    if (digitalRead(34))
        Serial.print("34");
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN,digitalRead(37));
}
```

Comment: No. They are not defined as `INPUT`s by default (??).

Comment: And if you manually set those pins to INPUT, does it start working?

Comment: Yes... that was the problem...

Comment: I am guessing that, since those pins are also PWM pins, the alternate function was stuck in PWM mode until you manually forced it to change. Possibly from some earlier sketch or something. I don't know the SAM chips well enough to know how the pin functions work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good practice is to set the pin mode for all the pins used by the sketch.

```
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    while(!Serial);
    pinMode(34, INPUT);
    pinMode(35, INPUT);
    pinMode(36, INPUT);
    pinMode(37, INPUT);
    pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
    Serial.print("Test");
}
```

The Arduino AVR core does set the pin mode to INPUT by default but the Arduino SAM core does not. The SAM MCU is much more advanced and allows turning on and off the ports, and a lot of other functionality.

Cheers!